# How to determine which sum is greater using integrals as a limit of sum?

Tags: integration, summation

Q10 here: http://goo.gl/1BNJLx

> Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}$ and $T_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}$ for $n=1,2,3,\dotsc$, then,
>
> (A) $S_n < \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$
>   (B) $S_n > \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$
>   (C) $T_n < \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$
>   (D) $T_n > \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$
>
> (Solution: A, D)

I understand that $S(n)$ is lesser than its limit at $n\to\infty$.
But does the same not apply for $T(n)$?

The value of the integrand and the limits remain same for $S(n)$ and $T(n)$.

So why is the integral of $T(n)$ at $n\to\infty$ lesser than the given value of $T(n)$?

Comment: They are the left and right Riemann sums for some $n$ of the integral given. Since the function is decreasing one will be an underestimate and the other an overestimate

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this chart, which illustrates $S_5$ and $T_5$, might help you understand.

$S_5 = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1n \times \frac{1}{1+(k/n)+(k/n)^2}$ is the grey area, while $T_5$ is the grey, blue and pink area.

The grey and  blue area is $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$

[image]

Comment: I get that but if we express the sum as an integeal, we have the same limits and the same integrand. So how can the result of the two same integrals be different?

Comment: The integrals (the grey and blue areas) are the same, but $S_n$ (just the grey area) is always less than this [answer A] and $T_n$ (the grey, blue and pink areas) is always greater than this [Answer D], for all finite $n$.